# Print Map WMS Geonetwork

Tags: wms, printing, geonetwork

I have installed geonetwork 3.10.4. When I print a raster WMS, a VERSION = 1.1.1 is put in the getmap, while the service is 1.3.0. This throws an error in the EXCEPTION field. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you are printing the WMS output, and how the metadata for the WMS service was entered/harvested.  That said, if the service is 1.3.0 only and if the printing is using 1.1.1 then that sounds like either  a harvesting error or a bug in the printing tool.

Comment: There was an answer to this question that looks like it should have been an [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/381654/edit), but posted by another user.  If this user was also you, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts